# Dynamically remove element from list based on test

Tags: list-manipulation

Suppose I have a list

```
l = {a, b, c, d, e, f....}
```

I would like to remove one of each pair `{x,y}` if some function `check[x,y]` returns `x`or `y` (or do nothing for that particular pair if the function returns `{}`). The order of the list is important. For example, if

```
check[c,e] === c;
check[a,f] === f;
```

and `check` on any other combination is empty, the final list should be

```
{a, b, d, e, ...}
```

I know how to write a for loop and do index-based removal, but is it a slicker way to do it using Mathematica's list manipulation functions?

EDIT: 
The `check` function should be non-overlapping in my usage, but in case if there is problematic overlap, say

```
check[a,e] === a;
check[a,f] === f;
```

both e and f should remain, since after removal of a (assuming position of a is earlier than f), there is no pair that can be formed with {a,f}.

Comment: I am presuming `Check` is intended to be your own, custom function but that name is already in use.  User symbols should start with lower case letters.

Comment: What happens if `check[a,b] == a` and `check[a,d] == a`?  Is it sufficient to remove `a`?  Should the second `check` be performed at all?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Good catch! Question edited.

Comment: Now I am wondering why `f` is removed and not `a` -- should the element that is *not* returned be removed?

Comment: It depends on definition of `check` of course; question  again edited for consistency. (It proves that I should go to bed instead...)

Comment: Honestly I still find this question underspecified.  The exact order and point at which an element is removed, and how that effects subsequent tests is still not clear to me.  Maybe you don't need to worry about all that ("The check function should be non-overlapping in my usage") but it makes for an interesting problem to consider the specifics.

Comment: polyglot, did you ever resolve the ambiguity in your specification?

Comment: I ask again: were you able to every fully specify this problem?  I'd give it another look if you were.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one implementation:

```
l = {a, b, c, d, e, f};
check[x_, y_] := If[MemberQ[l, x] && MemberQ[l, y], RandomChoice[{x, y}]]
Fold[DeleteCases, l, {check[c, e], check[a, f]}]
```

> {a, b, d, e}

**Edit**

A version that checks all subset pairs:

```
l = {a, b, c, d, e, f};
s = Subsets[l, {2}];
check[{x_, y_}] := If[MemberQ[l, x] && MemberQ[l, y], RandomChoice[{x, y}]]
(l = DeleteCases[l, check[#]]) & /@ s;
l
```

> {a}

As ployglot's edit observes, progressively removing check results from `l` results in less matches than using `Fold`, i.e.

```
Fold[DeleteCases, l, check[#] & /@ s]
```

> { }

Comment: You seem to have a very different interpretation of the question.  Would you take a look at my present answer and tell me if you still think you've got it right?  (I don't mean that condescendingly; rather I'm asking because I don't know for sure that *I've* got it right.)

Comment: @ Mr.Wizard - seems to depend how specific polyglot intends his example to be.

Answer (score 1):

You said that your `check` should be non-overlapping.  For that simplified case I believe this works:

```
ClearAll[check]
check[c, e] = c;
check[a, f] = f;
check[__] = {};

lst = {a, b, c, d, e, f};
DeleteCases[lst,
  Alternatives @@ Flatten[check @@@ Subsets[lst, {2}]]
]
```

> {a, b, d, e}

I'm still working on the more complex version.